# Tapestry-like nodejs framework

Tags: framework, node.js

Most nodejs Template engines which I know simply work by sending HTML from a template file and processing some special tags like placeholders, loops, conditions and code snippets. At this level, they are very similar to their grandparents PHP, ASP and JSP.

I was never happy which this level of programming, and after years, I found [Apache Tapestry](https://tapestry.apache.org/) (for Java). This framework still works with templates but abstracts functional components as much as possible: Grid (editable and sortable table), TextField&DateField, Errors (listing of form errors), EventLink, etc. All of them work out-of-the-box, including JavaScript and AJAX, with minimal need for (Java) coding and almost no HTML/CSS/JavaScript coding, but still flexible and extendable. Check out [Tapestry JumpStart](http://jumpstart.doublenegative.com.au/jumpstart/) for examples of the full feature palette.

I'm looking for something similar in nodejs, mainly for intranet applications and workflow tools, wherever there's not much time for implementation but the need for fully functional tables and forms.